# C - AddEdge Function in Graph

Tags: c, graph

I'm trying to create vertices that have lecture names.My aim is to connect the lectures if the lectures belong same student.But for start i make a prototype to create graph and vertices.But i cannot connect them with edges.I connect them but no output given.Program says test.exe stop working Here is my code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int count = 0;//count for adjlist place for vertices

    struct AdjListNode
    {
        char name[10];//lecture name
        struct AdjListNode* next;
        int id;//id for place of vertex in array of graph
    };
    struct AdjListNode *desti, *source, *newNode, *temp, *pCrawl; 

    struct AdjList
    {
        struct AdjListNode *head;  // pointer to head node of list
    };
    struct AdjList *array;

    struct Graph
    {
        int V;
        struct AdjList* array;
    };
    struct Graph *graph;

    struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(char name[10])
    {
        struct AdjListNode* newNode = (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode));
        memcpy(newNode->name, name, sizeof newNode->name);
        newNode->id = count;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        graph->array[count].head = newNode;
        count++;

        return newNode;
    }

    struct Graph* createGraph(int V)
    {
        struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
        graph->V = V;

        // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of array will be V
        graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList));

        // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < V; ++i)
            graph->array[i].head = NULL;

        return graph;
    }

    void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, char src[10], char dest[10])
    {
   //i create destination vertex and source vertex
        struct AdjListNode* desti = newAdjListNode(dest);//
        struct AdjListNode* source = newAdjListNode(src);

        //i try to connect them 
        desti->next = graph->array[source->id].head;
        source->next = graph->array[desti->id].head;
    }

    void printGraph(struct Graph* graph)
    {
        int v;
        for (v = 0; v < graph->V; ++v)
        {
            struct AdjListNode* pCrawl = graph->array[v].head;
            printf("name: %s -  ", pCrawl->name);
            printf("%s",pCrawl->next->name);  
    }
    }
    int main()
    {
        // create the graph given in above fugure
        int V = 5;
        struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V);
        newAdjListNode("BS11");
        newAdjListNode("CS10");
        newAdjListNode("MATH10"); 
        addEdge(graph, "CS10", "MATH10");
        addEdge(graph, "BS11", "CS10");
        printGraph(graph);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You're calling `newAdjListNode` in `addEdge` function. Don't create new nodes when creating edges, simply connect existing ones. There is a far simpler approach to this, lookup `Union-Find` data structure.

Comment: @PythEch  Thank for advice. But i have to do with graph due to it's homework. Is there any way to fix `addEdge`?

Comment: Union-Find is too a graph data structure. As for the problem, you should connect the existing nodes. Either store the nodes as `AdjListNode*` or search the entire array containing the same `char name[10]`.

Comment: I see your point. But i don't know how to add multiple edges in one vertex. Because `->next` allow to add one edge for each vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you may have a running program, your data structure design is broken. How would you add more than one edge from a given vertex?

An adjacency list representation of a graph has two parts:

- A set of vertices.
- A map: vertex -> list of vertices. // These are the adjacencies

In C it's convenient to put the vertices in an array. Then you can use indices into the vertex array as "handles" to the vertex info itself. This allows the map to also be an array: an array of lists.

With this, life gets much simpler:

```
// A vertex in this simple graph contains only its name.
#define NAME_SIZE 10
typedef struct vertex_s {
  char name[NAME_SIZE];
} VERTEX;

// An adjacency is just a vertex ID and a next pointer.
typedef struct adjacency_s {
  struct adjacency_s *next;
  int vertex_id;
} ADJACENCY;

// A graph is a set of vertices and a map from vertex IDs to adjacency lists.
typedef struct graph_s {
  VERTEX vertex[MAX_VERTEX_COUNT];
  ADJACENCY *adjacency_list[MAX_VERTEXT_COUNT];
  int vertex_count;
} GRAPH;
```

Now you can initialize the graph:

```
// Make a newly declared graph empty;
void init_graph(GRAPH *graph) {
  graph->vertex_count = 0;
}
```

Adding a vertex is just copying its data into a fresh location in the vertex array. We return its handle for future use.

```
int add_vertex(GRAPH *graph, char *name) {
  // Allocate a fresh vertex and empty adjacency list.
  memcpy(graph->vertex[graph->vertex_count].name, name, NAME_SIZE);
  graph->adjacency[graph->vertex_count] = NULL;
  return graph->vertex_count++;
}
```

Now we can add an edge from any vertex to any other given their ids by pushing a new adjacency onto the head of the "from" vertex's adjacency list. The node contains the ID of the "to" vertex.

```
void add_edge(GRAPH *graph, int from_id, int to_id) {
  ADJACENCY *a = malloc(sizeof *a); // Don't typecast malloc in C!
  a->vertex_id = to_id;
  a->next = graph->adjacency_list[from_id];
  graph->adjacency_list[from_id] = a;
}
```

Another capability you might want is to look up a vertex by name.

Comment: This gives me an error for this line `graph->adjacency_list[graph->vertex_count] = NULL;` **error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'ADJACENCY {aka adjacency_s}' and 'long long int')**

Comment: @M.Aktas You could try debugging a bit yourself. I missed a `*`.

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you but there is something wrong in the `init_graph` because program crashes right there. In the main i write `GRAPH *graph;` and the next line `init_graph(graph);`

Comment: No.  You need to declare a graph, not an uninitialized pointer to a graph.  `GRAPH graph; init_graph(&graph);`  Or if you'd rather, `GRAPH graph[1]; init_graph(graph);`  They both do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's worked. I want to print the graph how can i do that? Maybe i should start a new topic.

Comment: @M.Aktas No. You should figure it out yourself. I've probably helped you too much already. If you can't print the graph, then you don't understand what you've done.

Comment: I try to use `add_edge` for all day. As a result of this, should we know vertex id's? Before `add_edge` we don't assign any id's to vertices that we created. So my point is, do I miss something in your code or should we put `vertex_id` in `VERTEX` struct. I think therefore we can assign an id each vertex while we creating them.

Comment: `add_vertex` returns the ID of a newly created vertex. Assign each return value to an `int` variable. Now use these variables to add edges among the vertices, as many as you like.  `int a = add_vertex(g, "a"); int b = add_vertex(g, "b");  add_edge(g, a, b);`

Answer (score 2):

> Program says test.exe stop working

I would like to point out that you have a serious memory problem.
You use a global

```
 struct Graph *graph;
```

and local `*graph;` in the main which you initialize.

```
 struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V);
```

Yet, in the function

```
struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(char name[10])
```

you have global  `*graph` which has been not initialized! 
Therefore your program will not work properly.

You have two options to correct the problem. Fast but not recommended by me

1) Drop the declaration of the local *`graph,`to newAdjListNode(char name[10])

```
struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V);
```

and use the global *graph;

```
graph = createGraph(V);
```

2) Drop the declaration of the global      `struct Graph *graph;`
and pass local *graph to your `newAdjListNode(char *name, struct Graph* graph);`

This version of the program is presented below:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int count = 0;//count for adjlist place for vertices global!!??

    struct AdjListNode
    {
        char name[10];//lecture name
        struct AdjListNode* next;
        int id;//id for place of vertex in array of graph
    };

    struct AdjListNode *desti, *source, *temp, *pCrawl; // *newNode, // globals!?

    struct AdjList
    {
        struct AdjListNode *head;  // pointer to head node of list
    };

   //struct AdjList *array; //used where???
   //---------------------

    struct Graph
    {
        int V;
        struct AdjList* array; // 
    };

   // struct Graph *graph; - do not use globals, they create problems and colide with local variables of the same name.
    //--------------------------

    struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(char name[10], struct Graph* graph)
    {
        struct AdjListNode* newNode = (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode));

        memcpy(newNode->name, name, sizeof newNode->name); 

        newNode->id = count;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        graph->array[count].head  = newNode;
        count++;

        return newNode;
    }

    struct Graph* createGraph(int V)
    {
        struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
        graph->V = V;

        // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of array will be V
        graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList));

        // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < V; ++i)
            graph->array[i].head = NULL;

        return graph;
    }

    void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, char src[10], char dest[10])
    {
   //i create destination vertex and source vertex
        //struct AdjListNode* 
        desti = newAdjListNode(dest,graph);//
        //struct AdjListNode* 
        source = newAdjListNode(src,graph);

        //i try to connect them 
        desti->next = graph->array[source->id].head;
        source->next = graph->array[desti->id].head;
    }

    void printGraph(struct Graph* graph)
    {
        int v;
        for (v = 0; v < graph->V; ++v)
        {
            //struct AdjListNode* 
            pCrawl = graph->array[v].head;
            printf("name: %s -  ", pCrawl->name);
            printf("%s",pCrawl->next->name);  
        }
    }


    int main()
    {
        // create the graph given in above fugure
        int V = 5;
        struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V);

        newAdjListNode("BS11",graph);
        newAdjListNode("CS10",graph);
        newAdjListNode("MATH10",graph); 

        addEdge(graph, "CS10", "MATH10");
        addEdge(graph, "BS11", "CS10");
        printGraph(graph);
        return 0;
    }
```

You also shadow globals `*desti, *source, *temp, *pCrawl;` in

```
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, char src[10], char dest[10])
```

and global `struct AdjList *array;` is dandling unused. Clean your usage of globals. globals are bad programming practice.

The program logic still has to be improved but at least you have a proper memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

I just couldn't understand why you are using array because it makes no sense to use that pointer. If you don't want to get rid of that array pointer you can use something like that.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

int count = 0;//count for adjlist place for vertices

struct AdjListNode
{
    char name[10];//lecture name
    struct AdjListNode* next;
    int id;//id for place of vertex in array of graph
};
struct AdjListNode *desti, *source, *newNode, *temp, *pCrawl; 

struct AdjList
{
    struct AdjListNode *head;  // pointer to head node of list
};
struct AdjList *array;

struct Graph
{
    int it;
    int V;
    struct AdjList* array;
};
struct Graph *graph;

struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(char name[10])
{
    struct AdjListNode* newNode = (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode));
    memcpy(newNode->name, name, sizeof newNode->name);
    newNode->id = count;
    newNode->next = NULL;


    return newNode;
}

struct Graph* createGraph(int V)
{
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->V = V;
    graph->it = 0;

    // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of array will be V
    graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList));

    // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        graph->array[i].head = NULL;

    return graph;
}

void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, char src[10], char dest[10])
{;
    //i create destination vertex and source vertex
    struct AdjListNode* desti = newAdjListNode(dest);//
    struct AdjListNode* source = newAdjListNode(src);
    struct AdjListNode * temp=graph->array[0].head;
    //i try to connect them 
    graph->array[0].head=source;
    graph->array[0].head->next=desti;
    ++(graph->it);

    if(temp)
    desti->next=temp->next;
}

void printGraph(struct Graph* graph)
{
    int v;
    struct AdjListNode* pCrawl = graph->array[0].head;
    for (v = 0; v <= graph->it; ++v)
    {

        printf("name: %s   ", pCrawl->name);
        pCrawl=pCrawl->next;
}
        printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    // create the graph given in above fugure
    int V = 5;
    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V);
    //newAdjListNode("BS11");
    //newAdjListNode("CS10");
    //newAdjListNode("MATH10"); 
    addEdge(graph, "CS10", "MATH10");

    addEdge(graph, "BS11", "CS10");

    printGraph(graph);
    return 0;
}`.
```

Comment: The reason why i'm using array is I've found the base graph code on the internet. I configurate to my own purpose. Array from the base code. And it'S worked by the way. Many thanks.

Comment: Note that this code is not a solution I wrote it just to prevent you from segfault. Also you can use gdb to detect what you are violating.

Comment: @ÉŊÉ There are explanation in my answer what he is violating. Your code as you said did not resolve it.

Comment: @sg7 I obey your advice and changed the graph declaration. Many thanks. But you guys says this code does not bind the vertices. But it seems so. I just don't know how to print this which is a another topic. By the way I don't have to use array, any graph structure will be ok.